# How do I replace brackets using regular expressions in R?

Tags: regex, r

I'm sure this is a really easy question. I'm quite familiar with RegEx in R in the meantime, but I just can't get my head around this one.

Suppose, we have this string:

`a <- c("a b . ) ] \"")`

Now, all I want to do is to delete the quotes, the dot, the closing paranthesis and the closing brackets.

So, I want: `"a b"`.

I tried:

`gsub("[.\\)\"\\]]", "", a)`

It doesn't work. It returns: `"a b . ) ]"` So nothing gets removed.

As soon as I exclude the `\\]` from the search pattern, it works...

`gsub("[.\\)\"]", "", a)`

But, of course, it doesn't remove the closing brackets!

What have I done wrong?!?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `gsub('[[:punct:] ]+', ' ', a)`  It would be better to show the expected otuput as well. or `gsub('[][]|[.")]', '', a)`

Comment: Thanks! The second one works for me. Of course, the [[:punct:]] version would work too, but I don't want to remove ALL of the punctuation. Could you give me a hint why my version doesn't work. I want to understand the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- c('a b . ) ] "');
gsub('\\s*[].)"]\\s*','',a);
## [1] "a b"
```

When you want to include the close bracket character in a bracket expression you should always include it first within the brackets; that causes it to be taken as a character within the bracket expression, rather than as the closing delimiter of the bracket expression.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @akruns comment

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(gsub('[.]|[[:punct:]]', '\\1', a))
```

replace the period in the first set of brackets with whichever punctuations you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
> gsub("\\b\\W\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\\W", "", a, perl=T)
[1] "a b"
> gsub("\\b(\\W)\\b|\\W", "\\1", a, perl=T)
[1] "a b"
```